# i want to find out how many threads maximum use in dual core using C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I am using C#. I want to write the program using thread concept. I just  to know maximum how many threads can run  in dual core using C#. I attach my partial code:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(threadJobA);
Thread t2 = new Thread(threadJobB);
t1.Start();
t2.Start();
```

Comment: You need to do some serious reading, instead of posting a bunch of similar, confusing questions. You can run nearly *any* number of threads. They all seem to be running in parallel, but only Ncores will be executing at any given instant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Environment.ProcessorCount` to find out how many cores there are in the machine.

However, that doesn't limit the number of threads that you can start, that only tells you how many of the threads can run at the same time. In some situations there may be useful to start more threads than that, in some sitations less. It all depends on what the threads are supposed to be doing.